# Как лучше обработать исключение в классе В, которое может выбросить метод класса А в Java?

Tags: java, исключения

Объясняю ситуацию. Всё будет детально просто.
Имеется собственный класс исключений не проект.
Имеется класс-валидатор `FileValidator`. Данный класс содержит один единственный метод `isValidPath`, который может выбросить исключение.
Далее имеется другой класс `DataReader`. В данном классе имеется метод, который будет использовать метод-валидатор из класса `FileValidator` и там, соответственно, `FileValidator` может выбросить исключение, получится нужно будет 2 раза обрабатывать исключение и писать один и тот же текст в исключении.

```java
public class FileValidator {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();

    private FileValidator() {
    }

    public static boolean isValidPath(String path) throws ThreadException {
        if(path == null || path.isEmpty() || path.trim().isEmpty()) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.ERROR, "Incorrect path to file.");
            throw new ThreadException("Incorrect path to file.");
        }

        File file = new File(path);

        return file.exists() && file.length() > 0;
    }
}
```

```java
public class DataReader {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();

    public static List<String> read(String path) throws ThreadException {
        if(FileValidator.isValidPath(path)) {
            try(Stream<String> lineStream = Files.lines(Paths.get(path))) {
                return lineStream.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new ThreadException("Error reading from file", e);
            }
        } else {
            throw new ThreadException("Incorrect path to file.");
        }
    }
}
```

Вопрос в чем, чтобы не дублировать два раза код исключения, который второй раз появляется в классе `DataReader`  в таком виде `throw new ThreadException("Incorrect path to file.");`, хоть точно такая же строка с исключением есть в `FileValidator`-классе, как правильно организовать обработку исключения? А может и вовсе в валидаторе не нужно выбрасывать исключение?

Хочется, чтобы код был не громоздким и не содержал дубляжи этих исключений.

Comment: Важные вопросы: кто текст будет читать? действительно ли не нужно различать ситуации когда `path==null` и `file.lenght() == 0`? Возможно, что `path == null` это ошибка программиста, а `file.length() ==0` это ошибка пользователя (конечного или того, кто конфигурирует систему) и они обрабатываться будут по разному.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, `path` будет ручками вводить пользователь.

Comment: И как он может быть `null` в таком случае?

Comment: @RomanKonoval, логично...

Answer (score 1):

Может сделать что-бы isValidPath(String path) возвращал просто false если path пустой, а ошибку триггерить уже DataReader, если она вам нужна)

```
public class FileValidator {
private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();

private FileValidator() {
}

public static boolean isValidPath(String path) {
    if(path == null || path.isEmpty() || path.trim().isEmpty()) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.ERROR, "Incorrect path to file.");
        return false;
    }

    File file = new File(path);

    return file.exists() && file.length() > 0;
 }
}
```